# CKEditor and Simple Uploads Plugin with Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I'm using the CKEditor gem in a rails project and am using this plugin called Simple Uploads(http://ckeditor.com/addon/simpleuploads) that allows me as a user to upload an image into the wysiwyg editor.

However, my question is: does anyone have an example of a ruby script that I can insert into my rails project that'll run and process the image and put it into the S3 bucket for me?

Essentially, I've got this line of code in the config.js that specifies a script to run upon the image being selected.

```
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php';
```

I'd prefer the script to be a ruby file to handle the upload. Has anyone got this working for the CKEditor and Amazon S3?

Note: in the README for the CKEditor gem (See here: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) they mention running this link to generate models for Carrierwave and Imagemagick:

```
rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=carrierwave
```

So I've run that command, configured my S3 settings but not sure how to have that override behaviour so that it uses Carrierwave to upload?

I would seriously appreciate any help here as I'm quite stuck.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [rich gem](https://github.com/bastiaanterhorst/rich), which makes image management with the ckeditor incredibly simple, and then use either the [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or the [carrierwave gem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) for image uploading (I'd recommend carrierwave).

To upload to S3, you can use the [fog gem](https://github.com/fog/fog) with carrierwave, and [follow these directions](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3) to get fog configured with carrierwave.

[This link](http://www.javahabit.com/2012/06/03/saving-files-in-amazon-s3-using-carrierwave-and-fog-gem/) has a very detailed set of steps for getting going with fog, carrierwave, and S3. Just be sure to switch to the rich editor first.

Comment: Unfortunately, rich gem won't work for me, as I'm not meant to use an alternative to CK Editor. I appreciate your quick response and that it'd be helpful if I was integrating a new wysiwyg editor from scratch, but sadly no. It also doesn't have the drag and drop feature that I've integrated into my CK Editor customisations.